# Internet Explorer 9 CSS Text-Align Justify is not Justified but Centered within table cells

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, text-alignment, text-align, text-justify

Demo page: http://froyo.tv/test/index_table.php

[image]

IE9, Opera10

[image]

Firefox3, Chrome, AndroidBrowser, IE9 CompatibilityMode, IE8(I think), ...

From W3C:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#alignment-prop

> In the case of 'justify', this
>   property specifies that the
>   inline-level boxes are to be made
>   flush with both sides of the block
>   container if possible, by expanding or
>   contracting the contents of inline
>   boxes, else aligned as for the initial
>   value.

Why the text in IE9 and Opera10 are not Justified but centered text in table cell?

How to justyfy text, only with CSS?